# Tag "<a>" pode ser usada sem o "href"?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Existe alguma restrição ou problema em utilizar a *tag* `a` sem o atributo `href`?

Exemplo: `<a>teste</a>`.

Comment: Não, porém não terá funcionalidade alguma, claro que você pode adicionar funcionalidades depois com Javascript.

Comment: Qual seria a razão para fazer isso e não usar uma outra tag?

Comment: @Sergio Tenho um menu q é interno e externo. O externo usa a navegação tradicional com href e no interno o carregamento é via ajax. Como ja possuo todo o css desse menu, penso em apenas verificar se o usuario está logado ou não e remover os attr href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em HTML5 é válido e pode ser usado para depois ser completado por um *script*, conforme indica a [documentação oficial](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Algo assim:

```js
document.getElementById("link").href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
```

```html
<a id="link">Vai ter um link aqui</a>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Href.js).